# How do I get the position of a JButton on a GridBagLayout grid within a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, position, jbutton, gridbaglayout

so I am trying to make a program and in it I would like to find the position of a `JButton` on a `GridBagLayout` grid. I know I could do this using a variable/array for each button but is there some way to do it simpler? For example, is there a way where I can use something already in JButton or in GridBagLayout that I could use to get the position in just a one or a few lines?

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'position'?  The x,y co-ordinates of the component?  The index of it in the layout?  --  Why do you want this information, what will it do for the user?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`GridBagLayout#getConstraints(Component)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html#getConstraints(java.awt.Component)), it will return the `GridBagConstraints` for the supplied `Component`, just beware, you're dealing with the live copy, any changes you make WILL be reflected in the layout when it's revalidated

Oh and yeah, it would generally be easier to maintain a `List` or array of components, but that would depend on what you're actually trying to achieve.